# What is wrong with the button on the GUI

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtree

I have created a next button on the third panel of this GUI. This panel has a JTree with a collapsible checkbox on it, but when I open the tree the button disappears, when I check a box on the tree the button reappears. I want to stop the button from Disappearing, If you execute the code and go on to the third panel with the tree you will understand what I'm talking about, any ideas how to fix this?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;

public class MyWizard {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Wizard");
    private JPanel panelContainer = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panelFirst = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panelSecond = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panelThird = new JPanel();
    private JButton btNext = new JButton("Next");
    private JButton btNextTwo = new JButton("Next");
    private JButton btNextThree = new JButton("Next");
    private JRadioButton btLdap, btKerbegos, btSpnego, btSaml2;
    private JCheckBox btSan, btNFS, btYUMserver;
    private CardLayout c1 = new CardLayout();
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JLabel lblPicture, lblPictureTwo;
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("FMW Components");

    public MyWizard() {
        // tree code
        final DefaultMutableTreeNode accessibility = add(root, "DB Tier", true);
        add(accessibility, "RAC", false);
        add(accessibility, "Gateways", false);
        add(accessibility, "Datavault", false);
        add(accessibility, "Agent", false);
        add(accessibility, "Custom Databases", false);
        root.add(accessibility);

        final DefaultMutableTreeNode browsing = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("APP Tier");
        add(browsing, "IDM (OID, OVD)", false);
        add(browsing, "IAM (Access Manager)", false);
        add(browsing, "BIEE", false);
        add(browsing, "Forms and Reports", false);
        add(browsing, "Discoverer", false);
        add(browsing, "Apps", false);
        add(browsing, "Apex(4.2.1)", false);
        root.add(browsing);

        final DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
        final JTree tree = new JTree(treeModel);

        final CheckBoxNodeRenderer renderer = new CheckBoxNodeRenderer();
        tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);

        final CheckBoxNodeEditor editor = new CheckBoxNodeEditor(tree);
        tree.setCellEditor(editor);
        tree.setEditable(true);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        // tree code ends

        panelFirst.setLayout(null);
        panelSecond.setLayout(null);
        panelThird.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panelContainer.setLayout(c1);
        panelFirst.add(btNext);
        panelSecond.add(btNextTwo);
        panelThird.add(scrollPane);
        panelThird.add(btNextThree);

        panelFirst.setBackground(Color.white);
        panelSecond.setBackground(Color.white);

        panelContainer.add(panelFirst, "1");
        panelContainer.add(panelSecond, "2");
        panelContainer.add(panelThird, "3");
        c1.show(panelContainer, "1");
        panelThird.add(scrollPane);

        btNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                c1.show(panelContainer, "2");

            }

        });

        btNextTwo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                c1.show(panelContainer, "3");

            }

        });
        RadioButtons();
        Button();
        Buttons();
        CheckList();
        groupButton();
        ButtonsTwo();
        Image();
        frame.add(panelContainer);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(400, 310);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void RadioButtons() {
        btLdap = new JRadioButton("Ldap");
        btLdap.setBounds(60, 85, 100, 20);
        btLdap.setBackground(Color.white);
        panelFirst.add(btLdap);

        btKerbegos = new JRadioButton("Kerbegos");
        btKerbegos.setBounds(60, 115, 100, 20);
        btKerbegos.setBackground(Color.white);
        panelFirst.add(btKerbegos);

        btSpnego = new JRadioButton("Spnego");
        btSpnego.setBounds(60, 145, 100, 20);
        btSpnego.setBackground(Color.white);
        panelFirst.add(btSpnego);

        btSaml2 = new JRadioButton("Saml2");
        btSaml2.setBounds(60, 175, 100, 20);
        btSaml2.setBackground(Color.white);
        panelFirst.add(btSaml2);
    }

    public void Button() {
        btNext.setBounds(250, 240, 100, 20);
    }

    public void CheckList() {
        btSan = new JCheckBox("San");
        btSan.setBounds(60, 85, 100, 20);
        btSan.setBackground(Color.white);
        panelSecond.add(btSan);

        btNFS = new JCheckBox("NFS");
        btNFS.setBounds(60, 115, 100, 20);
        btNFS.setBackground(Color.white);
        panelSecond.add(btNFS);

        btYUMserver = new JCheckBox("Spnego");
        btYUMserver.setBounds(60, 145, 100, 20);
        btYUMserver.setBackground(Color.white);
        panelSecond.add(btYUMserver);
    }

    public void Buttons() {
        btNextTwo.setBounds(250, 240, 100, 20);
    }

    public void ButtonsTwo() {
        btNextThree.setBounds(250, 240, 100, 20);
    }

    public void Image() {
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("iconpic.png");
        lblPicture = new JLabel(image);
        lblPicture.setBounds(140, 5, 330, 270);
        panelFirst.add(lblPicture);

        ImageIcon imageTwo = new ImageIcon("iconpic.png");
        lblPictureTwo = new JLabel(imageTwo);
        lblPictureTwo.setBounds(140, 5, 330, 270);
        panelSecond.add(lblPictureTwo);
    }

    private void groupButton() {

        ButtonGroup bg1 = new ButtonGroup();

        bg1.add(btLdap);
        bg1.add(btKerbegos);
        bg1.add(btSpnego);
        bg1.add(btSaml2);

    }

    private static DefaultMutableTreeNode add(final DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, final String text,
            final boolean checked) {
        final CheckBoxNode data = new CheckBoxNode(text, checked);
        final DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(data);
        parent.add(node);
        return node;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MyWizard();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: `null` layouts nuff said (except, this is the second time I've seen this code, but from a different user)

Comment: `null` layouts, to be more precise.

Comment: the null layout is set on the other two panels, Even if I change that it does not fix the problem

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this is the 4th time you've presented this code with similar issues, the 4th time you've being recommended to make use of layout managers and at least the 3rd user name it's being presented under...I'm sorry, but you are seriously not helping yourself here...

Comment: `btNextThree.setBounds(250, 240, 100, 20);` is not going to help

Comment: if I set layout like you said, then I can't get the structure to be like I have been told to make it. That layout is with the .setBounds(250, 240,100,20)

Comment: please again without XxxRenderer and XxxEditor???, linked code in your previous question don't needed use null layout

Comment: ditto for everything MadProgrammer said about this person using multiple ID's to post the question 5-6 times while ignoring the advice given in those postings.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the components in `panelThird` to the same position.

```
panelThird.add(scrollPane);
panelThird.add(btNextThree);
```

Change that to for example to

```
panelThird.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panelThird.add(btNextThree, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Also, *remove* the second addition of `scrollPane` to `panelThird` some lines later. And really, you're making the task harder than it should be by using `null` layouts. Swing is designed to be used with layout managers and trying to do it otherwise you'll be fighting the  framework all the way. (Besides having a GUI that does not deal well with resizing, translations, different theming, ...)

Comment: yeah this works, the only problem is that the height of the next button is now massive, how can I reduce the height?

Comment: @ChaudhryCh I don't know what you want the final layout to look like. One possibility is using some other layout manager, like a vertical `BoxLayout` instead. Another is placing the button inside a `JPanel` and placing that in `panelThird`. (And deal with the button placement with an appropriate layout manager for the helper panel). Reading the layout [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) will help you choose the appropriate layout managers and how to use them.

Comment: @kiheru, this person has been given the advice to use layout managers several times on his previous 5-6 posts made under 3 different userids.